Dokku got nginx page instead of my RoR apps
I have a RoR apps running on dokku server (ver. 0.35.11) when on try to go on the app, using the ip, of the server, I got the nginx default page

Here is my nginx config file

server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/aramisweb-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/aramisweb-error.log;
  underscores_in_headers off;

  client_body_timeout 60s;
  client_header_timeout 60s;
  keepalive_timeout 75s;
  lingering_timeout 5s;
  send_timeout 60s;

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/wasm application/json application/xml application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://aramisweb-5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
    proxy_send_timeout 60s;
    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffers 8 4k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
    
  }

  client_max_body_size 1m;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 /400-error.html;
  location /400-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 404 /404-error.html;
  location /404-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /500-error.html;
  location /500-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }
  include /home/dokku/aramisweb/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

}

upstream aramisweb-5000 {

  server 172.17.0.5:5000;
}


Here is the port binding in the dokku config
DOKKU_PROXY_PORT:         80
DOKKU_PROXY_PORT_MAP:     http:80:5000 https:443:5000
DOKKU_PROXY_SSL_PORT:     443

I have no clue about what's wrong. Can somebody help me with that one?
If you need more information, please ask for it.

I don't see a root directive anywhere, which would tell nginx where to direct the traffic to. Maybe it is contained in "/home/dokku/aramisweb/nginx.conf.d/*.conf" (not shown in the post)?

@engineersmnky this location is empty, nothing in the nginx.conf.d folder. I have the feeling that my nginx config template was not the good one. But I can't find it's location to modify it

Do you have any domains associated with the app? What is the output of dokku domains:report $APP for this app?

@JoseDiaz-Gonzalez
      Domains app enabled:           true                     
      Domains app vhosts:                                     
      Domains global enabled:        true                    
      Domains global vhosts:         10.2.220.121```

Seems like you should add a domain to your app or disable domains. The vhost config isn't listening to a domain and the nginx page is the default site being rendered from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default (dokku might warn about this during an app deploy).

Are you sure this is the exact server block handling the app's requests? Could there be another server block acting as the default server? Do you see the coresponding entries at the nginx access log /var/log/nginx/aramisweb-error.log? Did you check the full nginx config using the nginx -T command?
